# What definition of integral is implied when expressing nonzero Chern number as the integral of Berry curvature?

Tags: magnetic-monopoles, topological-phase, berry-pancharatnam-phase, dirac-string

In defining a nonzero Chern number as the integral of Berry curvature over the parameter manifold: $$n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{S}{\mathcal{F}}{dS}$$ does the integral exist in a general Riemann sense, or is the integration carried out in some limited sense, e.g. as a principal value?
My physical intuition suggests that the Dirac string should cancel the rest of the flux if it is included in the integration, so that $n=0$ always. On the other hand if the integral is taken with initial exclusion of a small circle and then shrinking the circle radius to $0$, then the flux of Dirac string wil be left out and $n$ can take nonzero values.

Comment: It sounds like you have a specific situation in mind - could you clarify to which Dirac string you are referring?

Comment: @J.Murray: I would be happy to discover that I am throuroghly confused, but I thought a Dirac string always accompanies Dirac monopole and is therefore a general concept. As a reference let me point to p.605 of R. Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics, 2nd. ed.

Comment: The Dirac string doesn't contribute to the berry curvature. The berry PHASE is defined everywhere except at the Dirac string singularity, and when you change your gauge you move the location of the Dirac string and change the value of the berry phase. However, the berry CURVATURE is gauge invariant, finite everywhere, and doesn't see the string.